# How can I use a dev dependency locally on my machine only and not have to push it to the team repo?

Tags: git, webpack, git-stash, git-merge-conflict

I'm part of a time working with a remote repo.
I recently installed [a great Webpack plugin that plays a sound](https://github.com/posva/sounds-webpack-plugin) when Webpack finishes building the project. I love it but my team lead does not want it becoming part of the repo.

The problem is that every time I change branches, I have to reinstall the plugin and add it back to the webpack config. Sometimes, Git lets me get away with leaving it but sometimes it doesn't and tells me to commit or stash before proceeding with an action. I've done stashing but it becomes a pain because I need to constantly stash/un-stash and often rerun `install`/`add` and restart Webpack.

Is there any way I can make this part of Webpack and the project on **my machine only** in a way that is seamless and simple and doesn't affect anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the webpack config file has been added and committed to the repository. Usually such configuration files are not supposed to be committed as part of the repository from the beginning, because they vary a lot in different workspaces and cause conflicts if contributors commit and push their own versions. But as @BenPetty commented, a webpack config file should be committed. I am completely new to webpack, so please ignore my opinion here.

As it's already there and I have no idea about your repository, I'd suggest you try this workaround. Since you switch branches a lot, you could use `git worktree` to generate a worktree for every branch or even every revision. One worktree is independent from another and you can commit, pull or push in the worktree.

Say you have 3 branches `dev1`, `dev2` and `dev3`. The repository is now on `master`. You can use `git worktree add /foo/dev1 dev1` to create the path `/foo/dev1`, and `dev1` is checked out in it. Run `git worktree add /foo/dev2 dev2` and `git worktree add /foo/dev3 dev3` for the rest two branches. This way, you don't need to switch branches or clone a new repo for another branch. You can just enter the worktree path and install the plugin.

When `dev1` is done, you can use `git worktree remove /foo/dev1` to remove the worktree `/foo/dev1`. If you manually remove the path `/foo/dev1` first, you can then use `git worktree prune` to prune its information from the repository.

Comment: I disagree with your first point — webpack config should always be committed into the repository, as with any other build configuration files.